# Upgrading to Windows 8.1, I am not offered the option to keep apps and settings

Tags: windows, upgrade

I was trying to upgrade my windows 8 pro 64-bit (ZH-TW) to Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit (ZH-TW) and my pc would not get the option to keep apps and settings. I tried it on other computers that were installed with the exact same image for windows 8 and 
I have also tried changing the language and it still doesn't work. I have searched around online but I could not find any solution. I did not move my users folder,  like some posts relating to this suggested.

UPDATE: I found out that "Korean" was set as my system language but i have already set english
as default. It still shows korean as default now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade your Windows 8 from Windows Store, your desktop applications will be kept and style apps can be re-installed via Windows Store. I guess you tried the upgrade using DVD or iso image. Can you try that again from Windows Store?

[Reference (Windows 8.1 update tutorial)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-8/update-from-windows-8-tutorial)

For the system default language issue, it seems that Windows 8.1 follows the "default IME" setting. e.g. If you have Korean IME only, Windows 8.1 itself acts like Korean Windows 8.1 even if you installed an English one. I think your issue is somehow related to this so I recommend you to remove the Korean IME and restart the OS with English IME only. If it works fine, then add Korean IME again whilst keeping the default input method as English.